# (Python) Can't import gdal from osgeo

Tags: ppa, python3

I've always used Windows but decided to change to Ubuntu.
Now I'm trying to have my old code from school to work on Ubuntu but I get error on `from osgeo import gdal`

I've tried many fixes from the Internet but can't make it work.

If I try to `pip3 install osgeo` I get the following error:

```
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> osgeo
```

If I try `sudo apt-get -y install gdal-bin` I get:

```
gdal-bin is already the newest version (3.4.1+dfsg-1build4).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libboost-python1.74.0 libcasa-casa6
```

If I try `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa` I get:

```
Err:9 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
```

And checking ogrinfo version, it seems to be installed:

```
$ ogrinfo --version
GDAL 3.4.1, released 2021/12/27
```

In the Python code I tried changing `from osgeo import gdal` to `import gdal` or something like this, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Could someone help?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the error message when importing? Sure you're running python3 and not python2?

Comment: Hi, yes I'm using Python version 3.10.4. 
Everythig works fine now!!!

Comment: so what was the issue? if you think it might help others, you can write an answer